WhatsApp beeping sound with all sounds turned off
In a Galaxy A34, I turned off all sound and notification settings I could find (both on the device and WhatsApp). But I still get a beeping signal when I get a message from WhatsApp.
How can I turn that beeping sound off? I do not want to mute conversations in WhatsApp. So is it possible via the device?

Possibly related/dupe: How to turn off WhatsApp incoming message sound (in Redmi Prime 2 / MIUI 7.1)?
